# Transforming dataframe into feature attribute table in Processing plugin using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, qgis-processing

I am trying to develop a processing plugin using "Create New Script from Template".

In this plugin I have created a pandas dataframe. Assuming the df looks like this:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.25 | 0.84 |
| 0.36 | 0.4 |

---

Can I transform this df into features' attribute table?

Can I export this attribute table as a layer?

Comment: Yes it's a pandas daaframe. I want this specific one to be transformed into features. C1&C2 will be my headers in the attribute table and 0.25,0.84 will be feature 1 and 0.36,0.4 will be feature 2.

Comment: my dataframe consists of double numbers and my header which are string values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your specific case:

```
import pandas as pd

flist=['C1','C2']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = [(0.25,0.84),(0.36,0.4)], columns=flist)

vl = QgsVectorLayer("None", "temporary_table", "memory") #Adjust this line if you dont want a temp table
pr = vl.dataProvider()
vl.startEditing()
fieldlist = [QgsField(fieldname, QVariant.Double) for fieldname in flist]

pr.addAttributes(fieldlist)
vl.updateFields()

for i in df.index.to_list():
    fet = QgsFeature()
    newrow = df[flist].iloc[i].tolist()
    fet.setAttributes(newrow)
    pr.addFeatures([ fet ])
vl.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]